# Disable Wordpress tags to be indexed by Google

Tags: wordpress, google, tags

My client doesn't want the tag pages (www.example.com/tag/tagname) to be indexed by Google. How can I achieve this? Disallow in robots.txt doesn't work. Thanks!

**Robots.txt:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /tag/
```

Comment: Disallow in robots.txt *should* work. Can you show your robots.txt?

Comment: User-agent: *
Disallow: /tag/

Comment: that should work. How much time did you give it to work out? You know it can take several weeks until the change propagates?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. Than I'll just have to wait. Thanks.

Comment: You can submit your updated robots.txt directly through the Google Webmasters site that should speed up Google's response time to your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`robots.txt`  is the way to go, but it can take up to several weeks until reindexing.

You may be able to speed up the process - at least as far as Google is concerned - by signing up the site in question with [Google Webmaster Tools.](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)

Answer (score 2):

[Using meta tags to block access to your site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93710):

> To entirely prevent a page's contents from being listed in the Google web index even if other sites link to it, use a noindex meta tag. As long as Googlebot fetches the page, it will see the noindex meta tag and prevent that page from showing up in the web index.